# How to proper extend variables and override module style?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, best-practice, less

I am new to Magento and currently developing a child theme inherited from the Magento blank theme. I read the *developer documentation* and doing okay.

I created my own `style.less` in my web directory and load it besides the `style-l.less` and `style-m.less` from the parent theme. I also created a `variables.less` where I put my own variables.

In the `theme.less` I just override existing variables from the child-theme. Right now I am thinking it might be better, if there would be a way extending the variables instead of creating my own file. Also if I want to overwrite the styles of a module, I just define the style in my own `style.less` instead of overwriting the less file from the module itself, because I found no way doing that, only for the `.phtml` files.

How can I achieve above without loosing best code practices ?